# MySQL split row into 2 columns and group by, is that possible?

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-aggregation

I got a table with 2 columns app and grupo_id

`select count(*) total, app, grupo_id from devices d group by app, grupo_id ;`

output:

| total | app | grupo-id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

so the app I would like to split into 2 columns app-on and app-off and group them by grupo-id

Expected output:

| app-on | app-off | grupo-id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |

is that possible is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(app = 1) app_on, 
       SUM(app = 0) app_off,
       grupo_id
FROM devices 
GROUP BY grupo_id;
```

or:

```
SELECT SUM(app) app_on, 
       SUM(NOT app) app_off,
       grupo_id
FROM devices 
GROUP BY grupo_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for conditional aggregation

based on your first result

```
select grupo_id,
         max(case when app = 1 then total else 0 end) appopen,
         max(case when app = 0 then total else 0 end) appclosed
from t
group by grupo_id;

+----------+---------+-----------+
| grupo_id | appopen | appclosed |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|        1 |       1 |         3 |
|        2 |       5 |         0 |
|        4 |       7 |         2 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It may be possible to use this principal on your original query..